# some Cordova plugins still not supported by ionic3?

Tags: ionic2, ionic3

I installed ionic3 too early.  After installation, I figured that there are many cordova plugins still not supported by ionic3. For example the speech-recognition plugin.

It works on my ionic2 project, but when I upgrade to ionic3, I receive a blank page on my iphone screen (real device).

Is there anyway I can keep ionic3 but build the app in ionic2?

Thank you for any help :-)

Comment: Can you show your code for the implementation? There is no such issue.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping :-)   I am following this example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dPbT_kElSXA and I got a blank screen after I implemented the very first function (isSpeechRecognitonAvailable). I tried to test that on my iphone.

Comment: Really nice video.Thanks for sharing with us.This plugin still is in Beta.Hope you can put an issue there: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-native/issues/new

Comment: Issue reported.  I will update it here and I got an answer!